# svg mask not working on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, mask

I 'm trying to add a mask from an svg in Firefox but it's not working for composite elements.
[Example (you have to view it from Firefox)](http://goo.gl/RJksOT)

Comment: I solved it by defining a literal color as a fill instead of HEX. I have to make it repeatable now, which is another question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mask works by masking out areas where the mask colour is something other than black. The [mask image is initialised to transparent black](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#Masking) and then your mask contents are drawn on that.

Since your mask contents are black (#000000) then they have no effect and your mask does nothing.

Change to #FFFFFF or white to see the difference.